# Keyboard is open on click of selectField in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I have shown a dropdown in my app using the `selectfield` control. It is working fine when we click the arrow button but when user taps on text (input area), keyboard also getting opened. It is not an input field.

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    itemId: 'mypanel23',
    listeners: {
        fn: function (component, eOpts) {
            component.add({
                /***DropDown issue***/
                xtype: sessionStorage.voiceOver == "on" ? 'panel' : 'selectfield',
                /***DropDown issue***/
                cls: 'myusage_select_list',
                id: 'billedDD',
                itemId: 'myselectfield',
                hideOnMaskTap: true,
                /***DropDown issue***/
                html: sessionStorage.voiceOver == "on" ? "<select class='myusage_select_list' id='billedDD_Accessibility'></select>" : '',
                /***DropDown issue***/
                defaultPhonePickerConfig: {
                    cancelButton: {
                        text: BellMCare.util.config.getLocalizationValue('MobilityMyUsage_Cancel'),
                        listeners: {
                            tap: function () {
                                var uAgent = navigator.userAgent;
                                if (uAgent.match(/Alcatel/i)) {
                                    this.up('picker').setHidden(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    doneButton: {
                        //Sanity Issue - expiry date picker not working and screen struck                                
                        cls: 'pickerDoneBtn',
                        // Sanity Issue -End
                        text: BellMCare.util.config.getLocalizationValue('MobilityMyUsage_Done'),
                        listeners: {
                            tap: function () {
                                BellMCare.util.config.performanceLogs('PERFORMANCE LOGS | UI | Flow 4b | start ');

                                BellMCare.util.config.performanceLogs('PERFORMANCE LOGS | UI | Flow 4a or 4b  | Changed dropdown started  ');

                                var uAgent = navigator.userAgent;
                                if (uAgent.match(/Alcatel/i)) {
                                    this.up('picker').setHidden(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                listeners: {
                    change: function (selectfield, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                        if (oldValue != null) {
                            /**Dropdown Issue**/
                            BellMCare.app.getController("mobilityMyUsage").onBillCycleDropDownChange();
                            /**Dropdown Issue**/
                        }
                    },
                    focus: function (comp) {
                        var uAgent = navigator.userAgent;
                        if (uAgent.match(/Alcatel/i)) {
                            if (comp.getPhonePicker().isHidden()) {
                                comp.getPhonePicker().setHidden(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            /**Dropdown Issue**/
            Ext.getCmp("billedDD").innerHtmlElement.dom.addEventListener("change", function () {
                BellMCare.app.getController("mobilityMyUsage").onBillCycleDropDownChange();
            });
            /**Dropdown Issue**/
        },
        event: 'initialize'
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add editable:false

Comment: you can add a focus listener on selectfield, and stop the event with *event.stopEvent()*

Answer (score 2):

I managed it by the following code:

```
initialize: function(fld){
    var textboxEl = fld.element.query('input')[0];
    textboxEl.setAttribute('readonly', true);
}
```

Please let me know, if you have any doubt.